# create route network by connecting points together

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, xy

Below is a screendump of my .csv file. It contains 2 pairs of X,Y coordinate columns.

The dataset is about transport of chemicals or dirt by trucks from one destination to the other (one XY coordinate to the other).

I also have a network dataset containing all roads of the Netherlands, including maximum speed per road segment.

I want to map which roads were used during transportation.

I have to create a line-layer of shortest route over my network for every record.

So I want ArcMap to calculate the shortest route from start position to end position for every record in my database and make this a line shapefile.

How can I make such a line dataset based on the .csv file I have and the network dataset.

Do I do this with the network analyst?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please reword your question. It is unclear what do you want exactly? preferably share diagrams of your network and samples of your data

Comment: Above is a screendump of my .csv file. It is about transport of chemicals or dirt by trucks from one destination to the other. We want to map which roads were used during transportation. In my file I have a startposition and an endposition (both in XY coordinates). I want to create a line-layer of shortest route over my network for every record. So I want ArcMap to calculate the shortest route from start position to end position for every record in my database and make this a line shapefile.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to revise it with clarifications such as this.

Comment: Yes, network analyst will be part of your toolkit for this one. First you will need to [add your XY data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) (I suspect you may also have to save it as a feature class, as described in that document) and then run [route analysis](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Route_analysis/004700000045000000/).